# Jsonp ajax: Capture error 404

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am not able to capture the error http 404.
This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'callback_123',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
                ....
        } ,
        error: function(e) {
          console.log(e);          
        },
```

Somebody can help me?

Comment: Check your `url` is valid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture 404 status with jQuery AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931270/capture-404-status-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: It 's  not the same...I am using jsonp!!!!

Comment: Woops my bad. Is the following link helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035557/jsonp-request-error-handling